# How can I fix build procedure for Tauri app on Windows?

Tags: windows, rust, next.js, wix, tauri

I am an absolute beginner to to Tauri apps while building applications using Rust and NextJS (For UI). I am currently creating a Desktop app that is cross platform. The code compiles successfully. I use `npm run tauri build` to create builds for the application. The problem is that this command successfully builds .deb packages for Linux distros and .dmg for Macos. But fails to create an MSI installer for Windows.

I am sharing the logs for the build on Github actions. I was under the impression that this problem was probably only occuring on my code and my PC. But it seems it was failing on Github actions as well.

```
   Compiling tauri-app v1.0.0 (D:\a\tauri-app\tauri-app\src-tauri)
Finished release \[optimized\] target(s) in 9m 35s
Info Verifying wix package
Downloading https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/download/wix3112rtm/wix311-binaries.zip
Info validating hash
Info extracting WIX
Info Target: x64
Running candle for "main.wxs"
Error failed to bundle project: error running candle.exe: error running candle.exe: `failed to run C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\tauri/WixTools\candle.exe`
```

I have followed all the steps as specified in the documentation by Tauri at [Tauri documentation](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/building/windows). And also did exactly what was stated here at [Cross platform compilation](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/building/cross-platform). This could be a bug from Tauri as well. Because wix is failing instantly. I have tried removing WixTools from the directory as it automatically downloads it. But had no luck! So if anyone can help me out with this, that would be perfect!

Comment: Can you rerun it with the verbose flag like so `npm run tauri build -- --verbose` (note the extra `--` for npm to forward the arg to tauri)? This should give us a more helpful error.  

Edit: One common issue is using pre-release versions like `0.1.0-alpha`, WiX requires versions to be numeric-only in a major.minor.patch style

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing out the issue, I fixed it by adding the version in package.json, Cargo.toml and tauri.conf.json. Now everything just flows. I am pretty new to this. But we all gotta start somewhere. Once again Thank you!!!